# Why does my Chrome extension crash?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, httprequest

I think my chrome extension crashes because of many HTTP requests which is 90. I don't know what to do this function is fired when a button  is clicked and am I getting the data from the response text right or getting in a wrong way, can anyone help me with this?

Here is the code :

```
function trys() {

    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime(); 
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML="";
 for(var i=0;i<posts.length;i++)
 {
var s=0;
var po="https://m.facebook.com/browse/likes?id=";
var r="&actorid=";
var pid="&start=";
var full=po+posts[i]+r+page_id+pid;
    while(people[i]>=0)
    {
   pageRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
   pageRequest.open('GET',full+s,false)
   pageRequest.send(null)
   if(people[i]>30)
   {
    s+=30;
    people[i]-=30;
   }
   else
   {
    s+=people[i];
    people[i]-=s;
   }
console.log(pageRequest.responseText);
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML=pageRequest.responseText;
var exdata=document.getElementById("data").getElementsByClassName("_4mn c");
var emails=[];
 for (var j = 0; j < exdata.length; j++) {
    var k=exdata[j].firstChild.href;
    k=k.replace("chrome-extension://dhogakcpnhkbldjhilbhkgdhlnifhbhd/","");
    k=k.replace("?fref=pb&refid=53","");
    k=k.replace("&fref=pb&refid=53","");
    k=k.replace("profile.php?id=","");
    emails.push(k+"@facebook.com");
 }

 for(var x=0;x<emails.length;x++)
 {
    if(f_emails.indexOf(emails[x])==-1)
    {
        f_emails.push(emails[x]);
    }
 }
    }

 }

 var mn = new Date();
var nm= mn.getTime();
var time_taken=nm-n;
time_taken=time_taken/1000;
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML="success! <br> time taken:"+time_taken+" sec<br>";
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML+="Number of Emails:"+f_emails.length+"<br>";


for(var i=0;i<f_emails.length;i++)
 {
   document.getElementById("data").innerHTML+=f_emails[i]+"<br>";
 }


}
```

Comment: Why I always have to keep my breath until finished when reading a bunch of text like this? Have you ever heard of punctuation and paragraphs?

Comment: sorry am new to stack overflow

Comment: am sorry for that but you could give me hints what to do to improve

Comment: In my comment there are two hints included ...

Comment: ok i will consider this the next time i ask but could you help me with this question

Comment: Please define "crash". Have you taken a look at the console?

Comment: a pop up from google pops up and says extension is crashed please reload the extension